# send csv attachment without upload

Tags: php, csv, phpmailer

I found a lot of example how to create csv and send it as attachment.
All of these examples upload the file on the server. Is there a way to send the csv created without upload it so to be sent directly as attachment?

Comment: I don't think there is, but why not just upload on server -> send as attachment -> delete from server.

Comment: phpmailer runs on server and requires the file to be attached to be on the same server

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use addStringAttachment

see: https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer-PHPMailer-PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is! There are many ways of making CSV files, but a basic one is very simple:

```php
$data = [
    ['id', 'name', 'colour'],
    [1, 'Fred', 'blue'],
    [2, 'Jane', 'orange'],
    [3, 'Hassan', 'purple'],
];
$csv = fopen('file.csv', 'wb');
foreach($data as $line) {
    fputcsv($csv, $line);
}
fclose($csv);

//then later on, to send it with PHPMailer
$mail->addAttachment('file.csv');
```

Of course the data can come from anywhere - a database, a calculation, a remote web service, or whatever.

You could use output buffering to capture the CSV string output by `fputcsv` and pass that directly to `addStringAttachment`, which would mean you don't even need to write the file to disk before sending.